# How to create files that delete other files on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, ntfs

When I save a web page from Google Chrome, I get a HTML file and a directory with the resources. When I send one of them to the Recycle Bin, the other tags along as if they are linked by the file system. Here's an example:

[image]

What is this facility called and how do you create these links via Win32 system calls? It's not a hard link as this doesn't point to the same file. When I use `del` from a Command Prompt, it only deletes the one file, so it must be something Explorer is doing.

Comment: They are linked by name only. Windows Explorer, but not the Command Processor, knows that an HTML file is treated special and will look for a related folder that has a name derived from the HTML filename. See [Delete HTML file without deleting resource files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/delete-html-file-without-deleting-resource-files/295d8767-b6fa-4e65-ad87-ff8bae659811) for how to configure this behavior.

Comment: thanks that is such an old/obscure feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can create an HTML file named `foo.html` and a directory named `foo_files` and Explorer will pair these. It only will work with `.html` or `.htm` files.

Thanks to Remy.